# Days between dates

Tags: python, datetime

I need count days to password change in linux.

I know how to do this in python e.g:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start = datetime.date(2016,1,1)
>>> end = datetime.date(2016,2,28)
>>> end-start
```

But my date format is:

```
Oct 03, 2017
```

How I can calculate days to a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).
It is actually really simple:

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime("Jan 01, 2016", '%b %d, %Y')
d2 = datetime.strptime("Feb 28, 2016", '%b %d, %Y')
print "Delta (in days):", (d2-d1).days
```

And you'll get `58` as a result.

Comment: The OP clearly states that he knows how do do it in Python. He needs to do that in 'Linux', I assume in the shell.

Comment: @schwobaseggl - if that's the case, the question could do with some clarification/re-wording. My interpretation is that this is a python question, working out time until a 'password change in Linux'.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, by looking at the tags and by reading OP's question we can assume that what bothers OP is that he doesn't know how to calculate the days using the format of date he has.  I don't think he wants to do this with the shell.

Comment: And of course it's easy enough to run Python in a Bash command line using `python -c`